# Amplify DC voltage

Tags: voltage, amplifier, dc, amperage

Which is the best way to amplify DC voltage from 1.8 V to 3.2 V?

1.8 V is the output voltage of BeagleBoard-xM and is intended to be logic input voltage on ic [TX2 encoder](http://www.instructables.com/files/orig/FWW/CD13/GV525G0X/FWWCD13GV525G0X.pdf).

Should I concern about amperage?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For logic signals, you want a **level shifter**, e.g. http://www.nxp.com/products/logic/level_shifters_translators/

As it's a logic signal, current should not be a concern. Speed might be if you want very fast switching (MHz or more).

Answer (score 0):

This is what some beagleboard users recommend: -

[image]

It's bi-directional too so you don't have to worry about mixing IO lines up.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I 'm working on a breadboard, making TBX0108 inappropriate.

Comment: You can use FETs as bidirectional IO line controllers - they just need one resistor to work.

Comment: Use the PW package TSSOP and a breakout board.

Answer (score 0):

I think the most simple way to do it is with a transistor (bjt or fet) like this:

[image: Level shifter]

You should have a 3.2v power supply though. As for using a CI, you could use a level shifter or a opamp (which i think is unnecessary).